# My automatic image slider only shows the first two images

Tags: javascript

My automatic image slider only shows the first two images of the images array while tere are three images. I can't figure out why it is not working properly, I hope someone might know what is going wrong.

```js
var images = [];
var i = 0;

//image array
images[0] = 'https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784396';
images[1] = 'https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065867693';
images[2] = 'https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784396';


function changeImage() {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("slider").src = images[i];

    if (i < images.length - 1) {
        i += 1;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }

    setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
}

window.onload = changeImage;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Automatic Image Slider </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <img id="slider">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: #sidenote This is probably not the issue but I don't think it's a good idea to call setInterval recursively if it's not assigned to a variable. Try calling it outside the changeImage.

Comment: @EvansM. actually, you are right, that caused problems. Please make answer. ;) Lalala, if you call setInterval outside function, all works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/magjh1wy/

Comment: I have tried and it works now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is! I've modified your code so that it now will work, pay attention not to reinitialize the interval at every `changeImage()` call ;)

```js
//image array
var images = [];
images[0] = 'https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784396';
images[1] = 'https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065867693';
images[2] = 'https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784397';

var i = -1;
function changeImage() {
    "use strict";
    ++i;
    if (i >= images.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("slider").src = images[i];
}

setInterval(changeImage, 2000);

window.onload = changeImage;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Automatic Image Slider </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <img id="slider">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your condition `if (i < images.length - 1)` is true only for 0 an 1
If you do `if (i<=images.length-1)` you will get all the three images

Comment: or you can simply do ` if (i < images.length)`

Answer (score 0):

```
images.length = 3
```

but

```
images.length - 1 = 2
```

so

```
(i < images.length - 1)
```

this condition work inly for i = 0 and i = 1
use this condition instead

```
(i < images.length)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have tried but it still goes wrong with the third image. The image won't display because the source of the image is undefined.

Comment: Condition is ok, problem is somewhere else. If i is 1, it will be incremented, which is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code works with a little bug. Note that your first and last image is the same.

And the huge bug of your code is that you are creating a new interval at each `changeImage` call, so the last image is being placed but fastly replaced for the first image.

Remove the `setInterval(changeImage, 2000)` from the `changeImage` function and call it like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   changeImage();
   setInterval(changeImage, 2000)
}
```